# Как сделать filter в SQLAlchemy по полю PickleType?

Tags: sql, python, postgresql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

У меня в таблице есть поле типа `PickleType`, в которое я загружаю свой класс с перезагруженным методом сравнения `__eq__()`, как в sqlalchemy сделать `filter(Table.column == obj)`?

P.S. Так

```
session.query(Table).filter(Table.column == obj)
```

не работает, алхемия похоже вызывает оператор sql, а не `__eq__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вообщем с того что я видел, это не возможно. Если хочеться юзать `__eq__` то надо делать обычный filter(c загрузкой объекта в память и соответствующей скоростью).